# My supervisor is bad mouthing behind my back?

Tags: work-environment

I've had a couple co-workers tell me that someone told them not to talk to me and stay away from me. They wouldn't tell me who this information is coming from.

One of the girls that I'm very friendly towards told me that three people had come up to her and told her not to talk to me because I'm dangerous...which is not true. The last straw was last week, when I came in to work and the girl I'm friendly with was treating me differently. She was very standoffish and she would not make eye contact. I just thought she was just having a bad day. She finally spoke to me and informed me that it was brought to her attention that I've been throwing her under the bus to the supervisors. She and I do the same position and I replace the days that she's off.

So basically instead of taking responsibility of my actions, I'm pinning everything on her. I was baffled because I didn't do any of these things I was getting accused of. I told her that I didn't do it but she wasn't convinced and she continued to keep her distance and gave me a cold shoulder.

I said, okay, fine, I'm going to talk to my manager to get to the bottom of this because it's not fair for other people to manipulate you and turn you against me for no reason. That's when she believed me. But she doesn't want me to take it to the office because she doesn't want to get involved in the investigation process because what they are doing is basically harassment.

Now everything is back to normal between us now that she knows that it was all lies. This is starting to get to me so I'm considering quitting the position because this isn't the first time I've gotten blamed for other things in our position.

I strongly suspected my supervisor who was behind it. He micromanaged me. I dropped it and moved on...until the same lady started telling me that people are are still talking behind my back but she wouldn't say who it is.

Finally yesterday she confirmed that it is the supervisor I already suspected is saying these thinks about me. Basically he tells one thing then twists it around to other people when I'm not around and bad mouths me ... stating I'm lazy, I'm the reason why such and such is happening.

I want to quit the position where I directly work with him and complain to my manager but at the same time I don't want to throw my co-worker under the bus.

What would you do?

Comment: Country? Does your company have a HR department?

Comment: How many sources are pointing at the supervisor?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your supervisor, for whatever reason, is creating a hostile work environment for you.  There's not a lot that you can safely do to change that.  I would look to move out from under this supervisor.  I'll assume here that your supervisor also works for your manager.  I would not complain to your manager, or involve him in any way.  If you tell your manager one thing and your supervisor tells him another thing, you are just asking your manager to choose who to believe.  And, he may not choose to believe you unless you have a strong and trusting relationship with him.  If your manager does believe you, you may create an even worse relationship with your supervisor.  You might talk to other managers or supervisors that you know to see if they have any positions open that you might be qualified for. Please don't expect anyone else, for example your manager, to do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I would start looking for a new job.

None of your coworkers trust you, and apparently your manager wants to backstab you.

If your manager wants you gone, you will be terminated.

Why would you want to work at such a place?